Joomla API returns 500 error, but works when debug is enabled
I'm using a very vanilla install of Joomla 5.1, and trying to use the content API.
So a simple API call like...
curl -X GET "https://example.com/api/index.php/v1/content/articles" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H "Accept: application/vnd.api+json" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"  

...or even simpler, like...
curl -X GET "https://example.com/api/index.php/v1/content/articles" -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"  

...just returns...
{"errors":{"code":500,"title":"Internal server error"}}

...but the strange thing is, it returns the correct article json if I set Joomla's "Global Configuration" option "Debug System" to "Yes".
I've looked in all the log files, and can't find any clues, and also disabled all non core plug-ins.  It was the same in Joomla 4, before I updated.  I've not used the Joomla API much, as I've tended to write my own, but I'd like to use more core, moving forward.
Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
